# Loading dynamical images to UIScrollVIew

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

what I would like to do is to build a UIScrollView which contains a lots of images, the problem is that I don't want to load all the images to the scroll view at once for performance issues, so if someone can suggest and help me to build a UIScrollView which can add images on runtime, for example when I scroll left I get image and the next image is allocated when needed, paging on.

Comment: I succeeded I posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

Use this delegate method for add new image.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
```

// called on finger up if user dragged. decelerate is true if it will continue moving afterwards

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` and use its methods like

`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;`

which tells you about any offset changes in the Scroll View, and then you can load whichever image should appear at that offset at run-time. For that, you would have to keep track of the current offset and the page of your scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Apple's [PageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795) Sample Code
This could be a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    float currPos = scroll.contentOffset.x;

    BOOL movingRight = ( currPos / scroll.frame.size.width ) > 1 ? YES : NO ;

    if (movingRight) {
        NSLog(@"RIGHT");
        [photo2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"22.jpg"]];
        photo2.frame = CGRectMake(scroll.frame.size.width * 2, 0, scroll.frame.size.width, scroll.frame.size.height); 
    }else{
        NSLog(@"LEFT");
        [photo2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"33.jpg"]];
        photo2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scroll.frame.size.width, scroll.frame.size.height);        
    }


    //NSLog(@"%f",currPos);

}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    UIImage *img = [photo1 getImage];
    [photo1 setImage:[photo2 getImage]];
    [self.scroll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.scroll.frame.size.width, 0, self.scroll.frame.size.width, self.scroll.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
    [photo2 setImage:img];

}
```

Comment: Dude, collectionViews already do pretty much all that, don't reinvent the wheel.